# Open multiple netCDF files in a raster stack subsetting by z-value in R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I have about 30 netCDF files in a folder. Each of them looks like this:

```
> test
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 1680, 4320, 7257600, 8  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -56, 84  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/maps/GCMD_5km/10-18/BS5min.nc 
names       : X4.5, X9.10000038146973, X16.6000003814697, X28.8999996185303, X49.2999992370605, X82.9000015258789, X138.300003051758, X229.600006103516 
centimeter  : 4.5, 9.10000038146973, 16.6000003814697, 28.8999996185303, 49.2999992370605, 82.9000015258789, 138.300003051758, 229.600006103516 
varname     : BS
```

As you can see there is a "centimeter" section indicating the depth of the different layers contained within each file.

I want to stack all .nc files in a raster to later extract values for several points. **I am only interested in the first depth layer "4.5"**. I have tried this, hoping to select only the first depth layer for each .nc file:

```
filenames <- list.files(path="~/OneDrive/OneDrive - Universitat Autònoma de Barcelona/IIASA/maps/GCMD_5km/10-18/",
                        pattern='*.nc',full.names=TRUE)
soils <- raster::brick(filenames, lvar=4, level=1)
```

But this returns all layers (with additional warning messages).

Any help please? Thanks

Comment: Why `lvar=4`? The file only appears to have 3 dimensions. ncell is not a dimension it is nrow*ncol. What happens if you try it without the lvar argument? as in `soils <- brick(lapply(filenames, raster, level=1))`

Answer (score 0):

I can't really corroborate this without access to your data,
but maybe something like this will work for you:

```
soils <- lapply(filenames, raster::raster, lvar=4, level=1)
raster::brick(soils)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `test[[1]]`, `raster(test, 1)`  return the first layer?

Also `raster(filename)` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

`raster::brick(filenames)` only take the first file, i.e. same as `raster::brick(filenames[1])`

In your case, you need `raster::stack(filenames)`, you will get a huge raster object and then you can select what you want (e.g. first layer of centimeter)

Or probably try `soils <- raster::stack(filenames, lvar=4, level=1)`